# Where should I implement the user privileges

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, database-design

I am going to code a .NET application using C# and the database `PostgreSQL` via `Npgsql`. The application will allow users to access the database. Each user has his ID and Password. Some users have the ability to edit/update their data and the other don't, they only can read the data.

I would like to ask how/where should I implement the user privileges/permissions, on the database engine or on the application itself?

Comment: This probably belongs on programmers, as it's more of a higher level design issue.

Comment: See related question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/choice-of-authentication-approach-for-financial-app-on-postgresql/

Comment: I prefer to implement user management in the DB, where I can declarative enforce access control with roles and grants, and can use the same security model for different database clients. It depends a bit on your application, though, and there's no one right answer. This is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just handle it in the application. If user A has account type this then he can do 1 and 2 and so on. And then just call the appropriate methods based on that.